# Close connection in mongodb - app is stuck - is it good?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following mongo class to handle connection

```
export default class MongoService {
    constructor ({ config }) {
        this.options = {}
        this.connection = null
        this.config = config
        Object.assign(this.options, config.get('mongo'))
    }

async closeConnection(){
    this.connection.close()
}

async connect(){

    if (!this.options.url) {
        throw new Error('Db error')
    }

    return MongoClient.connect(this.options.url,{ useNewUrlParser: true })
}

async getConnection() {

    if (!this.connection) {
        this.connection = await this.connect()
    }

    return this.connection
}

async  getCollection(collectionName) {
    await this.getConnection()
    let db = this.connection.db(this.options.dbname)
    return  await db.collection(collectionName)
}
```

How I use in other file  :

```
try {
    var mongo = container.cradle.mongoService
    let collection = await mongo.getCollection('test')
    const cursor = collection.find({})
}catch(e){
    throw new Error(e)
}finally {
    await mongo.closeConnection()
}
```

My questions

1 - my service is good enough?

**2- do I need to user mongo.closeConnection in each time when I ask for collection** ?

if I do not use the close function (that I read is good) the app is stuck and not close 
for example I got resposne but nothing close it(if is needed) 
or I just need to remove the finally and forget from close